# If $X=\sin\Theta$ and $Y=\cos\Theta$ with $\Theta$ uniformly distributed, how can I compute the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$?

Tags: distributions, density-function, joint-distribution, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a random variable $\Theta$ uniformly distributed between $[-\pi ,\pi]$, two functions $X=\sin\Theta$ and $Y=\cos\Theta$. I know that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but not independent. I want to find the joint pdf $f(x,y)$ of $X$ and $Y$. How can I compute this?

I tried by using cdf $F(x,y)$, defined as:

\begin{align}
F(x,y)&=P(X<x,Y<y)
\\&=P(\sin\Theta<x,\cos\Theta<y)
\\&=P(\Theta<\arcsin x,\Theta<\arccos y)
\\&=P(\Theta<\max(\arcsin x,\arccos y))
\end{align}

(Is the last equality right?)

So:

\begin{align}
F(x,y) = \begin{cases}c_1\arccos x+c_2&,\text{ if }x,y\le \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \\ c_3\arcsin y+c_4 &,\text{ if }\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\le x,y\le 1\end{cases}
\end{align}

By imposing the property of cdf (i.e. $F(-1,-1)=0$ and $F(1,1)=1$):

\begin{align}
F(x,y) = \begin{cases}-\frac{2}{3\pi}\arccos x+ \frac23 &,\text{ if }x,y\le \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} 
\\ \frac2{\pi}\arcsin y &,\text{ if }\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\le x,y\le 1\end{cases}
\end{align}

Now, I want to find the joint pdf $f(x,y)$ as:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{\partial ^2 F(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}$$

How can I proceed (if the procedure that I used is correct)?

If the my procedure isn't right, how do I calculate the joint PDF of $(X,Y)$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: **A joint PDF does not exist.**  The variable $(X,Y)$ has a singular distribution: all its probability is concentrated on a lower-dimensional space (the unit circle).

Comment: Refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for typesetting math.

Answer (score 4):

We can derive a CDF, but not a valid pdf, as pointed out by @whuber. I will demonstrate how to derive the CDF.

You are correct up until here:
$$\eqalign{
F(x,y) &= P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) =  P (\sin(\theta) \lt x, \cos(\theta)\lt y) \\
&= P(\theta \leq \arcsin(x), \theta \leq \arcsin(y)).}$$

However, in your next step, you write $\max$ where you should have $\min$ (since $\theta$ must be less than both, it must be less than the smaller of the two). Therefore, we have

$$F(x,y) = P\left(\theta \leq \min\{\arcsin(x), \arcsin(y)\}\right).$$

Since $\theta \sim U(-\pi, \pi)$, it follows that

$$F(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
      0, & \min\{\arcsin(x),\, \arcsin(y)\} \leq -\pi \\
      \frac{\min\{\arcsin(x),\ \arcsin(y)\} + \pi}{2\pi}, & -\pi \leq \min\{\arcsin(x),\, \arcsin(y)\}\leq \pi \\
      1, & \pi \leq \min\{\arcsin(x),\, \arcsin(y)\} 
   \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Are you suggesting it's possible to compute a PDF for $(X,Y)$??

Comment: Which step is incorrect?

Comment: You haven't answered the question: it asks for $f,$ not $F.$  By offering a calculation of $F$ you are implying its mixed second partial derivative will yield $f,$ as stated in the question--but that derivative does not exist everywhere and does not produce a valid PDF.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer to reflect this. Better?

Comment: Better, yes--but not quite right.  There are plenty of CDFs that are not everywhere differentiable but still yield PDFs.  For instance, writing $u^{*}=\max(\min(u,1),0),$ consider $F(x,y)=x^{*}y^{*}.$ This is not second differentiable on the boundary of the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ but it has a PDF (it's the uniform distribution on the unit square). Thus, failing to be differentiable is not the reason the PDF doesn't exist. You need to invoke the second clause of my comment: computing $f$ from your $F$ and integrating $f$ does not reproduce $F.$

Comment: +1. The idea is clear -- but the use of $\arcsin$ is not correct, because *by definition* its values will *always* lie between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ and its domain is $[-1,1]$ rather than all the real numbers.

Comment: I was trying to get $F(x,y)$ explicitly from the solution proposed for CDF by DInb. I would have been satisfied to find a PDF such that integrated, returns the $F(x,y)$ (and not that it was necessarily the mixed derivative of $F(x,y)$). But since the last comment there seems to be no hope due to the domain of definition of the arcsin function. I venture to ask: could there be a solution in the sense of distributions (using the Dirac Delta)? Because the intent is to insert the PDF into a functional.

Comment: There will be a solution in the sense of distributions--and perhaps the best way to express it is in terms of $F$! I think we would need to know more about the functional in order to provide useful advice here.

Comment: @Whuber: Re not recovering the function by differentiating and integrating, is this equivalent to being absolutely continuous?

Comment: @MSIS What function, specifically?  Note that the bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ does not even have a continuous distribution.

Comment: @whuber: Thank you, I meant for general distribution functions, not necessarily this one. IIRC this condition of $\int f' =f $ is equivalent to f being absolutely continuous.

Comment: @MSIS That's a version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  The statement is correct for Riemann integrals but not for more general integrals and derivatives, such as Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\Theta \sim U(-\pi, \pi)$ so the density of $\Theta$ is given by $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$ in $-\pi, \pi$.
2. $F(x, y) = P(X \le x, Y \le y) = P(\Theta \le \arcsin(x) \wedge \arccos(y))$.
3. $
   F(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\arcsin(x) \wedge \arccos(y)} 1 \cdot d\theta
   = \frac{1}{2\pi}\arcsin(x) \wedge \arccos(y) + \frac{1}{2}.
   $

Comment: One problem with this analysis is that neither the arcsine nor the arccosine are uniquely defined, requiring care in explaining what they mean.  Another problem is that it begs the question: how can one describe some kind of a density related to $F$?